# LinkedIn "share" API not properly using the supplied "content.description"

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm successfully able to POST a new LinkedIn "share" of an image (not an actual article/page) with a comment via the API by making an OAuth-authenticated call like this:

URI: `POST https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?format=json`
Data:
`{
  "comment": "Some comment.",
  "content": {
    "title": "Some title.",
    "description": "My description.",
    "submitted-url": "https://cdn.website.com/images/image.png",
    "submitted-image-url": "https://cdn.website.com/images/image.png"
  },
  "visibility": {
    "code": "connections-only"
  } 
}`

However, when I view the resulting Share on linkedin.com the `description` near the image will not show my supplied "My description." and instead will show the `host` of the supplied image, i.e. `cdn.website.com` in this example. This is ugly and not desirable. It seems like they try to crawl the image as if it were a page, and are defaulting to the `host` instead of using my supplied description of "My description.".

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I can confirm that I have the identical issue :( The "description" field doesn't show up anywhere in the LinkedIn posts I make via their API either.

Answer (score 0):

You may choose only one of the following:

- *Show image* in LinkedIn share preview.
- *Show description* in LinkedIn share preview.

Proof: Two weeks fighting LinkedIn Support (*[Oh the humanity...](https://www.revoltlib.com/linkedin-social-share-url-broken-ticket.html)*).  But also look at share previews for sites that follow both of these rules: Wikipedia (has no image, has 1 description) and GitHub (has 1 image, has 1 description).

[image]
[image]

**Wikipedia:** [Description ONLY -- Works (but no image)!](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikipedia.org%2F)
**GitHub:** [Image ONLY -- Works (but no description)!](https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.github.com%2F)

I made a [test site, with only description,](https://www.revoltlib.com/linkedin-social-share-url-test.html) and it behaves according to the rule above-listed.  I'm well aware that the [Official Microsoft LinkedIn Share Documentation](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en) makes no mention whatsoever of this, but all direct experience seems to disagree.